# Exponential family of distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider the parametric class formed by the density functions defined as follows:

$$
f(y,\theta) = \frac {2} {\Gamma (1/4)}  e^{-(y-\theta)^4},\quad y\in\mathbb R,\quad\theta\in\mathbb R.
$$
Does this parametric class forms an exponential family?
I tried to write it in the form 
$$f(y, \theta)=q(y) e^{\phi(\theta)t(y)-\tau(\theta) }$$

I surely know that the right answer is yes, but how can I prove that?
Writing it in logarithmic form
$$f(y,\theta)=\ln \frac {2} {\Gamma (1/4)}-(y-\theta)^4$$

I assume that
$$q(y)= \ln \frac {2} {\Gamma (1/4)}$$

But here I don't have two distinct functions $\phi(\theta)$ and $t(y)$, because they are with exponent $4$.
And I also don't have a quantity $\tau(\theta)$.

What could I do?

Also, does this parametric class form a regular exponential family?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: please, this is driving me completely mad

Answer (score 0):

Exponential family, indeed: a parametrization uses $\tau(\theta)=0$, $q(y)=2/\Gamma(1/4)$,
$$t(y)=(y^4,y^3,y^2,y,1),\qquad\phi(\theta)=(-1,6\theta,-4\theta^2,6\theta^3,-\theta^4)^T.
$$

> **Take-home message:** the functions $t$ and $\phi$ used to parametrize exponential families of probability distributions are most often vector valued.

Comment: Great, i only had to develop that binome.
I tought about that but I wasn't sure about that only one parameter could be expressed by a vector of statistics.
I Aldo didnt know that $\tau(\theta)=0$ could ne possibile.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, and actually, the term tau(theta) is not needed since one can always include it in the scalar product phi(theta)t(y) by adjoining a coordinate 1 to t(y).

Comment: and so couldn't we say that $$t(y)=(y^4,y^3,y^2,y)$$
$$ \phi(\theta)=(-1,6\theta,-4\theta^4,6\theta^3) $$
while $\tau(\theta)= -\theta^4$
?
I mean, explaining $\tau(\theta)$ have we got a sufficient statistic in $t(y)$?
and also, is this parametric class a regulat exponential family?

Comment: I can't edit this comment anymore, I correct, $\tau(\theta)=+\theta^4$
(I forgot that is included like a difference in the factorization form).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family